# Aplicações GeneXus geradas para o C# têm performance mais lenta em 64 bits com relação à execução em 32 bits

Tags: desempenho, iis, genexus, 64-bits, 32-bits

Estou com um problema em uma aplicação feita em GeneXus que não me parece com muito sentido.

Minhas configurações do GeneXus são:

GeneXus X Evolution 2 Upgrade 7 Build 109528
Gerador C#
Environments que testei: Oracle, PostgreSQL e SQL Server

Quando executo uma determinada rotina com o pool no IIS configurado com a opção "Habilitar aplicativos de 32 bits" ativa, a rotina demora 1 segundo para executar. Se desativo essa opção no IIS e faço com que a aplicação rode em 64 bits, ela demora em torno de 5, 6 segundos.

Gerei os logs da execução do procedimento tanto em 32 quanto em 64 bits e me deparei com essas linhas:

64 bits:

```
08:47:03,059 [1] DEBUG DataStoreProvider - Start DataStoreProvider.Ctr, Parameters: handle '1', dataStoreHelper:GeneXus.Programs.pft0027p__default
08:47:03,059 [1] DEBUG GxDataStore - Setting handle '1'
08:47:06,126 [1] DEBUG DataStoreProvider - Start DataStoreProvider.execute, Parameters: handle '1'
08:47:06,141 [1] DEBUG Cursor - Start Cursor.createCursor, Parameters: handle '1', state '1'
```

32 bits:

```
08:47:36,938 [1] DEBUG DataStoreProvider - Start DataStoreProvider.Ctr, Parameters: handle '1', dataStoreHelper:GeneXus.Programs.pft0027p__default
08:47:36,938 [1] DEBUG GxDataStore - Setting handle '1'
08:47:36,993 [1] DEBUG DataStoreProvider - Start DataStoreProvider.execute, Parameters: handle '1'
08:47:36,993 [1] DEBUG Cursor - Start Cursor.createCursor, Parameters: handle '1', state '1'
```

A diferença de execução de uma arquitetura para outra, ao menos nessa parte da execução, está na linha aonde o log diz "Setting handle".

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia que possa me dar uma luz, eu agradeço bastante.

Comment: Tenho algumas dúvidas: 1) Essa diferença de tempo acontece mesmo executando uma segunda vez esse objeto ? porque a primeira vez pode acontecer sim que demora alguns segundos.   2) Se o tempo se mantém, teríamos que analisar o que faz o programa pft0027p, principalmente antes do primeiro acceso ao bando de dados. Para ver se esta sendo utilizando algum recurso que não esteja optimizado para 64 bits.

Comment: Obrigado pelo contato Pablo, vamos aos esclarecimentos: 1) A diferença de tempo exorbitante acontece apenas uma vez, na segunda vai praticamente instantâneo... a questão é que com o recycle do pool o problema volta a acontecer... 2) No caso o tempo não se mantém na segunda execução da rotina, fica rápido...

Answer (score -1):

Esse tempo inicial é por causa da compilação que o ASP.NET, que faz que se carreguem todos temporais do aspnet cada vez que se altere a pasta bin (um novo assembly compilado ou alguma alteração no web.config). (mais detalhes [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723))

Existe uma optimização que se pode utiliza principalmente em ambientes de prototipação (onde esse tipo de alterações pode acontecer mais seguido).

Consiste em colocar esta configuração no web.config (requer do Framework 4.0)

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation optimizeCompilations="true">
      <assemblies />
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Essa configuração se gera automáticamente a partir da versão GeneXus 15 Upgrade 5 ([SAC #41361](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?es,,,41361))

Comment: Pablo, muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda.

Vou fazer meus testes aqui e retorno assim que tiver os resultados.

Comment: Pablo, fiz os testes aqui e infelizmente não funcionou da maneira que eu esperava, após um recycle no pool de aplicativos a aplicação continuou ficando lenta na primeira execução de uma rotina, coisa que da segunda vez que a rotina é executada antes de reciclar o pool não acontece... =(

Comment: José, reiniciando o pool não tem essa demora com 32 bits? porque essa demora inicial pode-se apresentar ao reiniciar o pool, mas em qualquer caso (32 ou 64 bits). A optimização que comentava aplica quando se fazem atualizações. Se o problema somente acontece com 64, então acho que seria melhor enviar um código de exemplo (xpz) para o suporte pegar com o Profiler. Com isso podemos ver a causa da demora.